# Strange error for PayPal - Uncaught Error: Window closed

Tags: angular, typescript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am having a problem with PayPal integration. Currently, same and exact problem is appering on PayPal demo application. To reproduce, please:

- go to [PayPal Demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)
- Click "Pay with paypal"
- Close the window that opened automatically

You will get an error in the console.

I was trying to find a solution [here](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1107), but no real solution has been provided. Could it be fixed somehow currently?